# Mac doesn't boot: "Failed to create activation request"

Tags: mac, catalina

I'm facing an issue that cannot boot to OS because the mac shows the Activate Mac page and with an error message:

> Failed to create activation request

I removed the device from my iCloud account and the strange thing is the Mac is still shown in iCloud find.

also when I'm trying to install new Catalina from USB it's loading first time with apple logo then took me to recovery mode (Activate Mac).